# ¿Cómo mostrar código XML dentro de HTML?

Tags: html

Tengo lo siguiente dentro de html.

```
<code>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <country>Columbia</country>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

El problema es que cuando se visualiza en el navegador se muestra de la siguiente forma:

```
Empire 
Burlesque 
Bob Dylan 
USA 
Columbia 
10.90 
1985
```

Comment: con < [pre](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/pre) > no te sirve?

Comment: Probé eso, pero no funcionaba, lo puse antes de <code>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de la etiqueta [**`xmp`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/xmp) (elemento de ejemplo) la cual hace que el código dentro de ellas **no** sea intepretado por el navegador,  y lo muestra con un tipo de fuente monoespaciada

```html
<xmp>
  <catalog>
      <cd>
          <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
          <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
          <country>USA</country>
          <country>Columbia</country>
          <price>10.90</price>
          <year>1985</year>
      </cd>
  </catalog>
</xmp>
```

Como dijo Mariano, la etiqueta xmp está obsoleta, por lo cual hice este simple script que quizá te pueda ayudar, (claramente se puede mejorar)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#parseHTML').click(function(){
  
    const pre = '&lt;';
    const post = '&gt;';
    
    var preHTML = $('#htmlArea').val();
    var postHTML = preHTML.replace(/</g, pre).replace(/>/g, post);
    
    $('#result').html(postHTML);
  
  });

})
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}

button{
  width: 100%;
}

div{
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="htmlArea" placeholder="Ingrese su código HTML"></textarea>
<button id="parseHTML">Mostrar código HTML</button>
<div id="result">RESULTADO</div>
```

Comment: El mismo enlace que estás incluyendo de MDN dice que está obsoleto.